# Make jquery working on dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

i have this bootstrap carousel script, but the trigger is an appended button. I'm junior in js and i'm not that sure how should i us on or delegate to make it working and change the code. Could you help me with this? also maybe tell me how should i use it. Thnx in advance

```
<script>
      /* activate the carousel */
    $("#modal-carousel").carousel({interval:false});

    /* change modal title when slide changes */
    $("#modal-carousel").on("slid.bs.carousel", function () {
      $(".modal-title").html($(this).find(".active img").attr("title"));
    })

    /* when clicking a thumbnail */
    $(".galz .gal").click(function(){
        var content = $(".carousel-inner");
        var title = $(".modal-title");

        content.empty();  
        title.empty();

        var id = this.id;  
        var repo = $("#img-repo .item");
        var repoCopy = repo.filter("#" + id).clone();
        var active = repoCopy.first();

        active.addClass("active");
        title.html(active.find("img").attr("title"));
        content.append(repoCopy);

        // show the modal
        $("#modal-gallery").modal("show");
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use event delegation

```
$(document).on('click', 'element', function() {
    // Your function code
});
```

Comment: thnx guys, it's working and now i know how to use "on" by myself :P

Answer (score 2):

You can call click in this way also

```
 $(document).delegate('.galz', 'click', function() {
       //your code

    });
```